# Move hover panel position depending on where the content is

Tags: 2013

I'm in SharePoint 2013 and I have a content search web part which shows a catalogue of items which have product pictures and descriptions.

I have a hover panel which shows a larger picture when moused over.

The problem I have is SharePoint always puts the hover panel on the right, which means it tends to cover my refiners when viewing items on the right.

My content is shown by three thumbnail pics going across the page, so ideally I’d like the hover panel to come from the right for the first pic, come from the middle and cover the thumbnail of the middle item and come from the left on the third pic – hope that makes sense! I’ve searched and cannot find any information on how to do this.

I’m guessing the best way to do this would be in javascript in the hover panel template – is this the right approach or is there a better way?

Comment: changing the Hover Panel template is the best approach. Apply some javascript and css to achieve as you wanted for your requirement.